# Can StackExchange apps. store the website data in their own database?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stackapps

My app. intends to view the stackechange sites' data and then if needed store them in my database for later retrieval and viewing with slight modifications.

Is this allowed?

The app. intends to merge and store answers enhanced with notes if needed in a personal DB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Stack Exchange API Terms of Use](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), they don't prohibit storing data returned by the API.

Mostly, we just stipulate attribution requirements in keeping with our [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) approach to basically everything.